# Spring Boot Upgrade Error - Invalid bean definition with name org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In an attempt to upgrade spring boot to the latest version 2.1.1 & spring framework to 5.1.3 in a java based web application, I get the following error

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' defined in null
```

The complete stacktrace is as follows. Any thoughts on troubleshooting further would be helpful

```
Failure starting application: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.event.TransactionalEventListenerFactory]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=transactionalEventListenerFactory; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:894)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ParserContext.registerBeanComponent(ParserContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.registerTransactionalEventListenerFactory(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:111)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:358)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
```

Thanks!

**Update 1**

The issue was suppressed by turning on bean overriding that was by default disabled in spring boot 2.1.0 RELEASE

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

After this workaround, the application startup fails with an OOM error as below

```
Application run failed java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Comment: There's a mention in the error about the classpath of the application. Mind adding it to the question? It seems like there is a double reference to internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory somehow.

Comment: The classpath involves more than 100+ third party and application specific libraries. Btw, the classes in the error message aren't classes or beans that we configure in the application code. It looks like something internal to spring transaction management.

Comment: @AndyDufresne, did you find the actually issue?

Comment: @PraveeshP - Since this has been more than a year ago, I don't recollect much but I think we had to go with the below property.

Answer (score 14):

I was having a similar problem with my tests after an update to Spring Boot 2.1. In my case was solved setting the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` to `true`. Maybe this can help in your case too.

Comment: Yes, that did resolve the error but I guess its just suppressing the problem temporarily. How do we troubleshoot and fix the root cause?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being more helpful, maybe you have two classes annotated with @EnableTransactionManagement this annotation loads ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration and this one defines a Bean named internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory. If this is the case you must remove one of the @EnableTransactionManagement annotation or maintain the property `allow-bean-definition-overriding` to allow Spring Boot to work as in previous versions.

Comment: This helped me to get my tests running again, but I agree with Andy, that another solution is required in some cases. However, Andy, in your case this might be exactly the right solution, though. Impossible to say without more code. Bean overriding was true before Spring Boot 2.1 anyway, so the behaviour of you application should stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, but the root cause of my issue is, that there are multiple `tx:annotation-driven` tags defined in `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).