# Test service method that has @PreAuthorize with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

In Spring Boot 1.4.1, I want to do unit testing (not integration testing) on a service method that has restricted access with @PreAuthorize.

The problem is the @PreAuthorize doesn't seem to be checked when launching the test solo from Eclipse (haven't try with mvn test yet).

Then, if I miraculously manage to run the test correctly, I will try to work with the StudyService interface, not the impl.

Here is my test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMethodSecurity {

    private static final Long STUDY_ID = 1L;

    @Mock
    private StudyRepository studyRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private StudyServiceImpl studyService;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        given(studyRepository.findOne(STUDY_ID)).willReturn(ModelsUtil.createStudy());
    }


    @Test
    public void findByIdWithoutAccessRightTest() {
        Study study = studyService.findById(STUDY_ID);
    }
}
```

This is the service :

```
@Service
public class StudyServiceImpl implements StudyService {


    @Autowired
    private StudyRepository studyRepository;


    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('DOES NOT EVENT CHECK SYNTAX")
    public Study findById(final Long id) {
        return studyRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

The test succeed, which is a fail.

Comment: You might want to look into `@WithUserDetails`.

Comment: Have you found solution for this? I have the same problem - @PreAuthorize isn't checked in tests and endpoints always return http 200, while they should return http 403.

Comment: @user2551317 Yes, it's with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true), I will write a complete solution onb monday if I remember it.

Comment: @Julien I would be so grateful if you could write full solution to this problem, i'm getting BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor' when I add this annotation. Maybe this is mixing with other annotations.

Comment: @user2551317 I wrote my solution below. About your bug, I don't remeber having that one, meybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834643/spring-boot-upgrade-error-invalid-bean-definition-with-name-org-springframewor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's how I make it work :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class StudySecurityTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudyService service;

    @MockBean
    private StudyRepository repository;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    public void testAsAnonymous() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloakUser(id = LOGGED_USER_ID, username = LOGGED_USER_USERNAME, authorities = { "ROLE_USER" })
    public void testAsUser() {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are interrested in `@WithMockKeycloakUser`, ask me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test Spring Security annotations, you need to use `SpringRunner` which will create Spring Context and inject Spring Security code to proxy class.

How to test Spring Security you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test.html).

Comment: Thank you. So I added @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration but it doesn't change the result (test succeed)

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your test class with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
```

Your method should look like this

```
@Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
@WithAnonymousUser
@Test
    public void findByIdWithoutAccessRightTest() {
        Study study = studyService.findById(STUDY_ID);
    }
```

You can not test security without loading at least security context.

You may want to look at this example:

```
public ApplicationUser getApplicationUser() {
    ApplicationUser applicationUser = (ApplicationUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return applicationUser;
}

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import com.arpit.security.user.ApplicationUser;

public class BaseTest {

    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void mockApplicationUser() {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = mock(ApplicationUser.class);
        Authentication authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
        SecurityContext securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).thenReturn(applicationUser);
    }

}
```

Taken from: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/05/mocking-spring-security-context-unit-testing.html

And I suppose that your service method has syntax errors on purpose? (missing parenthesis and wrong quotes?)

Comment: On @PreAuthorize, yes. Thanks I'll check that as soon as possible.