# How to use a custom 'TransactionAttributeSource' with Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

In Spring 5 there is `ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration`.

This defines:

```
@Bean
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
public TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource() {
    return new AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource();
}
```

When I define my own `TransactionAttributeSource` in my own configuration like:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource() {
    return new RollbackOnAllTransactionAttributeSource();
}
```

I got the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'transactionAttributeSource' defined in class path resource [...]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=[...]; factoryMethodName=transactionAttributeSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [...]] for bean 'transactionAttributeSource': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAttributeSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] bound.
```

How can I use a custom 'TransactionAttributeSource' with Spring 5.
(It works with Spring 4.)

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I found it here: [Spring Boot Upgrade Error - Invalid bean definition with name org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834643/spring-boot-upgrade-error-invalid-bean-definition-with-name-org-springframewor)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to enable bean definition overriding (as it may cause some unwanted bean definition overriding in future code changes), you can use the following solution and generate a bean from this class:

```
public class AnnotationTransactionAttributeSourceReplacer implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        try {
            String[] beanDefinitionNames = registry.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            for (String beanDefinitionName : beanDefinitionNames) {
                BeanDefinition beanDefinition = registry.getBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName);
                if (isAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(beanDefinition)) {
                    registry.removeBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName);
                    registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName, getCustomTransactionAttributeSource());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanCreationException("CustomTransactionAttributeSource can not create because Transaction timeoutValues are not handled");
        }
    }

    private boolean isAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource(BeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
        String className = beanDefinition.getBeanClassName();
        if (className == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (className.equals(TransactionAttributeSource.class.getName()) || className.equals(AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class.getName())) {
            return true;
        }
        if (beanDefinition instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition) {
            MethodMetadata methodMetadata = ((AnnotatedBeanDefinition) beanDefinition).getFactoryMethodMetadata();
            if (methodMetadata == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return methodMetadata.getReturnTypeName().equals(TransactionAttributeSource.class.getName()) || methodMetadata.getReturnTypeName().equals(AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class.getName());
        }
        return false;
    }

    private BeanDefinition getCustomTransactionAttributeSource() {
        return BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(CustomTransactionAttributeSource.class) //your custom class
                .setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
                .getBeanDefinition();
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```